# Incremental Build aspnet_compiler

Tags: asp.net, iis, command-line, iis-7

I am using aspnet_complier command for building website, first time it is compiling complete website i.e all pages, but after modification on the site, it is again compiling all the pages. It should compile only that pages that have been changed or modified.

And other things are 
1) How can i speed up the aspnet_compiler ?
2) how can i exclude warning from the output ?

Please suggest on the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx), "You can also recompile an application in place after adding new source files to it. The tool compiles only the new or changed files unless you include the `-c` option".

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be an option to hide warnings.

Speed up the process by making sure the machine where you run it is appropriately powered. eg. an SSD disk should probably help.